# How to run csproj on .net runtime

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

Let's say I have csproj and if I run msbuild from command line on it, it's generates a target TaskCli.dll

> msbuild TaskCli.csproj
>   `TaskCli -> bin\Debug\TaskCli.dll`

Which tool I should use to run the TaskCli.dll? I am using .net framework 4.5.

Edit: I changed the output type as console app and msbuild generating a .exe file. Then I can run the .exe file from command line. Thanks for all your helps.

`TaskCli -> bin\Debug\TaskCli.exe`

Comment: Are you using .net core or "classic .net" (=> what is the target framework?)

Comment: classic .net framework

Comment: So you built a library? (=> dll) what do you expect from "running" a library that has no entry point (main function)?

Comment: It's not a library, there is a main method in it. MSBuild generating a dll out of it. I guess I should ask it to generate exe and then run it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Link Libraries (**DLL's**), created with the `.net Framework`, are not directly executable.

An Option for testing these, without executable would be [**PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Add-Type -Path "..\TaskCli.dll"
$yourClass = new-object YourNamespace.YourClass
$yourClass.yourMethod("myParameter")
```

Another Commandline Option is using [**RUNDLL32**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/164787/info-windows-rundll-and-rundll32-interface), which allow you to invoke a function exported from a DLL:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE <dllname>, <entrypoint> <optional arguments>
```

Comment: Hmm, dotnet core runtime allow me to execute dll. If the project is targeted for dotnet core, I can run it like `dotent TaskCli.dll`

Comment: @Ulka You can't cross `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core`. These are different frameworks.

Comment: I know, .NET core allow me to run dll, I was wondering is there a way for .NET framework.

Comment: I know I can run the project from visual studio, but what is the equivalent way to do it from command line.

Comment: @Ulka So you're looking for CLI options to run your DLL, right? And you're working on a Windows PC?